# Reading from flask.session returns an empty list

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-session

My Flask app has the following route that renders a grid of images alongside a WTForm for user input. My desired behaviour is to preserve current sample of images when the form is submitted but was not valid. My idea was to store the sample from the last GET request in the flask.session proxy. However, when the sample is read from `session` an empty list is returned.

I have set the session type to `filesystem` in the app's config.
I've read that the data stored in session is in fact written to cookies and therefore needs to be JSON-serialisable, but since we're dealing with a list of strings this is not a problem.

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def hello():
    input_form = TagForm()
    data_index = g._index
    if request.method == 'GET':
        sample = sampling.sample(16, data_index)
        print('storing sample')
        session['curr_sample'] = sample
        print('stored sample:')
        print(session['curr_sample'])
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print('reading sample')
        sample = session['curr_sample']
        print('stored sample:')
        print(session['curr_sample'])
        if input_form.validate_on_submit():
            # commit tag to db
            return redirect(url_for('hello'))
        else:
            flash('Could not commit.', 'danger')
    return render_template('grid.html', sample=sample, form=input_form)
```

Here is the output from the server:

```
storing sample
stored sample:
['2_3_3.png', '2_11_15.png', '2_11_15.png', '2_14_15.png', '2_17_11.png', '2_11_11.png', '2_18_15.png', '2_10_0.png', '2_7_12.png', '2_3_2.png', '2_9_15.png', '2_19_12.png', '2_17_12.png', '2_5_11.png', '2_10_2.png', '2_11_11.png']
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2020 15:08:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2020 15:08:48] "GET /cdn/2_11_11.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2020 15:08:48] "GET /cdn/2_17_12.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2020 15:08:48] "GET /cdn/2_5_11.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2020 15:08:48] "GET /cdn/2_9_15.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2020 15:08:48] "GET /cdn/2_3_2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2020 15:08:48] "GET /cdn/2_10_2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2020 15:08:48] "GET /cdn/2_18_15.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2020 15:08:48] "GET /cdn/2_11_15.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2020 15:08:48] "GET /cdn/2_3_3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
reading sample
stored sample:
[]
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2020 15:09:40] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

Comment: Is the SECRET_KEY defined?

Comment: It is set in the config

Comment: Please show the imported packages/modules